# Drawing route between two markers over polylines

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-polyline, google-directions-api

I am currently developing an Android application for bus transport, as I use Google Maps API v3. The city, for which I am developing the app, recently had it transport scheme changed so I can't use GTFS as the information in it is outdated. I have drawn all the bus routes via the [Interactive Polyline Encoder Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility), after that decoding them and use the value in a busRoute class with the following structure:

```
public class bus {
public Polyline polyline;
private String route;
private String schedule; ...
```

All the bus routes are stored in an array allBuses and each has similar structure:

```
final bus busB1 = new bus(mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().color(0xFF393185).clickable(true).addAll(decodedPathbB1)),"\nТерминал Меден Рудник – бул. „Александър Георгиев – Коджакафалията” – бул. “Захари Стоянов” – ул. “Тодор Александров” –  ул. “Спортна” – Терминал Юг -  бул. “Христо Ботев” – бул. “Стефан Стамболов” – бул. “Никола Петков” – ул. “Петко Задгорски” – ул. “Георги  Калоянчев” – ул. “Димитър Аврамов” –  ул. “Аква Калиде” – Терминал Изгрев\n" + "\n" + "Терминал Изгрев –  ул. “Аква Калиде” – ул. “Димитър Аврамов” – ул. “Георги Калоянчев” – ул. “Петко Задгорски” – бул. “Никола Петков” – бул. “Стефан Стамболов” – бул. “Христо Ботев” – Терминал Юг – ул. “Спортна” – ул. “Тодор Александров” – бул. “Захари Стоянов” – бул. „Александър Георгиев – Коджакафалията – Терминал Меден РудникРазписание от Терминал Меден рудник\n\n","Разписание от Терминал Меден рудник\n" + "\n" + "делник (от понеделник до петък)\n" + "от 04:40 до 06:00 – 20 мин.\n" + "от 06:00 до 20:00 – 12 мин.\n" + "от 20:00 до 22:20 – 20 мин.\n" + "от 22:20 до 23:10 – 25 мин.\n" + "\n" + "празник (събота и неделя)\n" + "от 05:00 до 06:00 – 20 мин.\n" + "от 06:00 до 13:56 – 14 мин.\n" + "от 13:56 до 16:36 – 16 мин.\n" + "от 16:36 до 20:20 – 14 мин.\n" + "от 20:20 до 20:40 – 20 мин.\n" + "от 20:40 до 23:10 – 30 мин.\n" + "\n" + " \n" + "\n" + "Разписание от Терминал Изгрев\n" + "\n" + "делник (от понеделник до петък)\n" + "от 04:40 до 05:40 – 20 мин.\n" + "от 05:40 до 06:06 – 26 мин.\n" + "от 06:06 до 20:06 – 12 мин.\n" + "от 20:06 до 20:20 – 14 мин.\n" + "от 20:20 до 22:20 – 20 мин.\n" + "от 22:20 до 23:10 – 25 мин.\n" + "\n" + "празник (събота и неделя)\n" + "от 05:00 до 06:00 – 20 мин.\n" + "от 06:00 до 13:56 – 14 мин.\n" + "от 13:56 до 16:36 – 16 мин.\n" + "от 16:36 до 20:20 – 14 мин.\n" + "от 20:20 до 20:40 – 20 мин.\n" + "от 20:40 до 23:10 – 30 мин.");
```

For the bus stops I am using markers, which I declared as a separate class and put in an array like this:

```
allBusStops = new Marker[]{
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(42.451865, 27.418863)).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.busstop)).title("Терминал Меден Рудник").snippet("Б11,Т1,9,9а,Бо,Б1,Б2,Б12,Т2")),
```

To connect the bus routes to the corresponding bus routes I'm using splitting the snippet and comparing it with the tag of each bus.

Now I want to make a field, by which the user can write an address and the application will give him the directions to the nearest bus stop, to tell him which bus should take and if necessary which buses should switch to go to the desired destination.

For the first part it can be done by Directions API with WALKING travelMode to the LatLng of the nearest marker.

How can I make the Directions API show the route to the desired destination only over the predrawn polylines or is there a way without using the Directions API to do so?

Comment: Each bus stop will have need to be a waypoint to ensure the route follows them.

Comment: True, but the issue is that I must pass 257 waypoint and the limitation of the Directions API is 23 per request. So if the user wants to go all the way through the city there is no way I could limit the request to 23 waypoint even if i divide the map to many segments and write a logic from filtering only the nearby ones.